# Securing High-Availability on Partitioned Database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, availability-groups, sharding

I have a 90GB SQL 2012 database I am sharding over 3 database and I plan on growing as more clients are coming. A new customer came to us with a demand to know on we secure high-availability in our platform. This is a very important customer with a high potential.

I am using SQL with PartitionDB wrapper. I have read about the built-in [backup feature](http://partitiondb.com/database-types-backupdb/). I am not sure if this is enough, I want to use [AlwaysOn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff877884.aspx) but I don't know how to use it on partitioned database.

We manage a security platform for our customers where we need to secure isolation for each client. Our production environment currently holds 3 small customers with 90GB but now we need to plan for our major customer, comes with special requirements.

Some of the requirements demands we give 24/7 real-time DB access to his data, special addins fitting his solution including code and data structure, and 24/7 availability. It's very important customer and we need to adjust to his needs. We are built-in Azure, on-premise database.

We are using partitiondb, the product, and not the services. Their solution helped us manage our databases, the product works as an Object-Oriented modelling which fits great with our generic platform behavior. Now we are testing our new architecture with stress tests reaching over 100GB per customer with over 1K concurrent users. So far looks good from performance aspects.

Now we are dealing with the high-availability requirement. We understand we can use BackupDB but it's not enough for our customer. We require a cluster-like real-time solution. Using AlwaysOn seems quite unsustainable when dealing with multi-tenant programming same we have, as we may have more than 20 databases. I was wondering if someone else, had the same incident, and how it worked for him? Talking about SaaS systems with multi-tenant cloud programming.

Comment: I'm not familiar with PartitionDB, but it looks like they advertise [Advice & support by the most professional DBA’s 24/7 365](http://partitiondb.com/). So what info did their support team give you? Can you add that to the question?

Comment: Is this Azure? Are you *forced* to shard? I can't think of a reason right now why I would shard a 90GB database which is small on any modern hardware.

Comment: Also, there is no such thing as a partitioned database with SQL Server. The unit of partitioning is the table (actually, the index).

Comment: Actually I agree that anybody in the cloud/azure need to think of a scale-out solution, whether scaling of the application servers to the database servers. Try [AlwaysOn on Azure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn249504.aspx)

Comment: @Johns scaling out is a last resort solution because it creates enormous efforts. It's being done that after you can no longer easily scale up. I admit 90GB might be much for Azure to handle because of the 500GB limit but on premised this is nothing.

Comment: I agree that scaling out is usually an enormous effort, this is why we chose  pdb which simplified things for us. Our system is a classic "white-label" system and partitioning was done from day one.